# How to programmatically scroll in iPad for safari browser

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, scrolling, ipad

I want to implement window.scrollTo(x,y) functionality for iPad. It works in desktop but does not work for iPad. There are certain solutions already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012449/how-to-programmatically-scroll-window-on-ipad) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012449/how-to-programmatically-scroll-window-on-ipad/45592234) which did not work for me.

I have implemented these solutions as below:

> Component markup:

```
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}"/>
```

> Controller:

```
onRender :  function(component, event, helper){
    var scrollPosition = component.get('v.scrollPosition');
    if($A.get("$Browser.isIPad")){
        var container = document.getElementById("scrollerDiv");//This is outermost div of the outermost component.
        setInterval(function() {
        container.scrollTop += 1;
        }, 20);

        //ANOTHER TRY 

        /*var x = window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);
        clearTimeout(x);
        }, 0);*/

        //ANOTHER TRY 

        //var scrollerDiv = document.getElementById("scrollerDiv");
        //scrollerDiv.scrollTop = 0;
    }
    else{
        window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);  //Works in desktop.
    }
}
```